# Is it possible to synthesize VHDL code with variable in it

Tags: vhdl, hdl

If I have variables in my *VHDL*, will it be synthesizable (using softwares like *RTL* compiler)?

I doubt it because it changes its values instantly. I am using `std_logic` now.

Answer (score 6):

As Brian Drummond writes, you can synthesize processes with variables and the
netlist result depends on whether the variable is read before or after assign.

If the variable is read **before** assign, then the variable transfers a value
from a previous time to the current time, and storage (typically flip-flop
or latch) is required to keep the state over time.  Example code, where both
`sig` and `var` will result in flip-flops, since the variable `var` is read
before assign:

```
process (clk_i) is
  variable var : std_logic;
begin
  if rising_edge(clk_i) then
    sig <= var;
    var := arg;
  end if;
end process;
```

If the variable is read **after** assign, then any previous variable value is
unused, so no storage is implemented in the netlist.  The variable is thereby
only used to make an intermediate value, for example to ease code writing.
Example code, where only `sig` will result in flip-flop, since the variable
`var` is read after assign:

```
process (clk_i) is
  variable var : std_logic;
begin
  if rising_edge(clk_i) then
    var := arg;
    sig <= var;
  end if;
end process;
```

In more complex (realistic) code, it may be difficult to ensure that variables
are only read after assign, thus without inferring unintended storage
(flip-flop or latch).  A useful coding style is to assign all variables with
unknown (`'X'`) at the start of the code.  If a variable is then read before
assign, the bug is typically revealed early on in simulation and debugging.
Example code:

```
process (clk_i) is
  variable var : std_logic;
begin
  if rising_edge(clk_i) then
    var := `X`;  -- Ensure variable assign before any use to avoid storage
    var := arg;
    sig <= var;
  end if;
end process;
```

Note that in simulation it typically requires additional effort to include
variables in waveforms; ModelSim for example shows process variables in a
separate "Locals" view.  If variables that hold state are left out of the
waveform then debugging is much more difficult, since the waveform then
shows only half the story.

A practical coding style is therefore to use variables only for intermediate
values in a process, thus always doing read after assign.

Comment: +1 for the great explanation. Would you consider rewriting "if the variable is *used* before/after" as "if the variable is *read* before/after"? I think that being specific in this case would make your point more effectively.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, variables used inside a VHDL process are synthesisable.

Comment: But how will this be incorporated in the synthesized netlist. Or how will the equivalent hardware look like

Comment: That depends on the way you use the variable. It can represent either combinational logic (gates) or a register, depending on whether it is assigned before or after it is used in a clocked process.